# Kotlin - Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Intent was expected

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm very new to Kotlin and I'm getting an error stating `Kotlin - Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Intent was expected` and I'm unsure how to resolve this.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

**Code Snippet:**

```
  val webURL: String? = dataMap["uri"]
    val intent: Intent
    intent = if (!webURL.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webURL))
        intent.data = Uri.parse(webURL)
    } else {
        Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    }
```

**Note:**

The error occurs on the line:

```
intent.data = Uri.parse(deeplinkURL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if condition is true, you don't return anything here
simply add `intent` line right before else

Answer (score 2):

```
val webURL: String? = dataMap["uri"]
val intent: Intent

intent = if (!webURL.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webURL))
} else {
    Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
}
```

If you are going to assign a value to a variable or property from an `if`/`else` expression, you need both the `if` and the `else` branches to evaluate to the desired type. And, you do not need to provide the `Uri` to the `Intent` twice.